# Handle Null value from cloud firestore if Text is null or not filled by user

Tags: flutter

how to handle if text field return null and substitute with text for example " NOT AVAILABLE "
I have this text field for example:

```
Text(
                                                  "${data['name']}",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w300,
                                                      color: Colors.white),
                                                ),
```

in this case if collection from cloud firestore is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Text(
    data.['name'] ?? "Not available",
     style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 15,
         fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
         color: Colors.white),
      ),
),
```